# Unable to attach application 'chrome.exe' (PID) using this PC Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-2015

In visual studio 2015 I am getting this error and unable to attach the process with chrome. If i press yes then it ask same for the more process. If I press No then it just disappeared and application still not attach. It happened whenever I start debugging the application and takes almost 15 minutes to debug and after that visual studio show this popup. I tried with the google but nothing found.

I have a 64-bit OS with 64-bit chrome and before today it was working fine.
could anyone please guide me how to resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Debug → Attach To Process, and change "Attach To:" to "Native Code".

Comment: this works for 2017, will check on 2015 and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Properties =>web

View image guide 1:
[image: view image guide 1]

View image guide 2:
[image: view image guide 2]